# Is there any way to improve this query on my PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've recently created a data warehouse with postgres. In a specific table I've loaded a total of 29 Mi rows.

I'm trying to identify identical lines through a generated MD5. The problem is that is taking more than a day to process and eliminate duplicates.
All the columns used are with index.

The query:

```
DELETE FROM 
    elos_sched_2 es 
WHERE
    ES.SCHED_ID IN 
         ( SELECT
               ELOS_SCHED_2 
           GROUP BY
               HASHID 
           HAVING 
               COUNT(1) > 1 )
```

This is the "EXPLAIN" generated with the query:

```
Delete on elos_sched_2 es  (cost=7190318.45..7191769.30 rows=11673374 width=38)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7190318.45..7191769.30 rows=11673374 width=38)
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=7190317.88..7190319.88 rows=200 width=40)
              Group Key: "ANY_subquery".min
              ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=6618114.99..7152680.62 rows=15054907 width=40)
                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=6618114.99..7002131.55 rows=15054907 width=41)
                          Group Key: elos_sched_2.hashid
                          Filter: (count(1) > 1)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=6618114.99..6676481.86 rows=23346749 width=41)
                                Sort Key: elos_sched_2.hashid
                                ->  Seq Scan on elos_sched_2  (cost=0.00..1606287.49 rows=23346749 width=41)
        ->  Index Scan using idx_sched_id_elos_sched_2 on elos_sched_2 es  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=14)
              Index Cond: (sched_id = "ANY_subquery".min)
```

There's any opportunity that can be seen just with this result?

Thanks!

Comment: `IN` some large set of values is often slow. Take a look at examples at bottom of this doc page [Delete](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) for an alternate method using a join. Per the above "In some cases the join style is easier to write or faster to execute than the sub-select style."

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64667468/edit) your post with valid SQL query. Then delete above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be way quicker. First extract and materlialize the SCHED_ID-s to delete and then delete them.
If your Postgres version is below 12 then remove `MATERIALIZED` from the query as CTE-s are always materialized.

```sql
with MATERIALIZED delete_list(id_to_delete) as
(
  select MIN(SCHED_ID) 
  from elos_sched_2 
  group by HASHID
  having COUNT(1) > 1
)
delete from elos_sched_2 
where SCHED_ID in (select id_to_delete from delete_list);
```

**Edit**
Btw, what if there are more than one duplicate per `hashid`? The query logic should be inverted.

```sql
with MATERIALIZED keep_list(id_to_keep) as
(
  select MAX(sched_id) 
  from elos_sched_2 
  group by hashid
)
delete from elos_sched_2 
where sched_id NOT in (select id_to_keep from keep_list);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took a few hours but I've reached the necessary. And thanks for this second suggestion, indeed it's better.